# How to get started with Ruby programming language with Java background?

Tags: ruby

I am intermediate in java but as one of the company requirements they are looking for JAVA+RUBY programming language..
  Can anybody help how to get started with Ruby I need to get it done in next one month so that I can crack the interview of the company...
 I wanna know how does Ruby work like compiler, is it platform independent or how does byte code generated..
I must be able to write the small level programs in Ruby..
Like in java First I need to download JDK den getting started with programs..
How about Ruby what all I need to install in my computer..

Thanks..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516/getting-started-with-ruby-development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[To Ruby From Java](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-java/)
[To Ruby From Other Languages](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/)
[Download Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)

Answer (score 2):

[The Pickaxe book](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)

[Why's guide](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/)

Comment: The "pickaxe book" is the slang name for "Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide" (so called because of the image of a pickaxe on the cover of the printed version).  This book is a great introduction to the language as well as a useful reference.  Best of all, it's free and very easy to read.  I would definitely recommend this book as the first read for anyone looking to learn the language.  It covers installing Ruby as well as both low- and high-level details of the language, all while providing lots of sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of surprised no one has mentioned [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) yet.

One of its strengths is the ability to natively call Java classes, so you can use a lot of the frameworks from Java that you're already familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the Ruby Koans is another great way to learn
http://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans

Answer (score 1):

Pragrog books are always good:

http://pragprog.com/titles/fr_j2r/from-java-to-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

http://tryruby.org/

Once you do the 15 minute walk-through, go here:

[Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)

Answer (score 0):

To Ruby from Java:

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-java/

That is the official site for Ruby and will be able to point you to language downloads and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

How about the Ruby language web site: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/

Also, I would advise you not to try and come across as a ruby expert in the interview after only playing with it for a month. It's better to err on the side of honesty, because a good interviewer will be able to tell when you are faking it... or worse, it will show when you start working.

Ruby is a cool language... have fun!